# What is the return type of the function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this function

```
 export const getColor = (color: string): string => colors[color] || colors.white;
```

but I get warning line under `colors[color] || colors.white` saying that `Unsafe return of an any typed value`
I made sure that this method accepts string and returns string but I don't know what is the exact problem + it's forbidden to use `any`

```
export const colors = {
  'dark-grey': '#606060',
  'light-grey': '#909090',
  'slate-grey': '#7889a0',
  'olive-green': '#8fd683',
  'light-blue': '#0371ff',
  'dark-gray': '#4b6c89',
  'blue-700-new': 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  azure: '#1676ff',
  blue: '#1676ff',
  white: '#fff',
  black: '#000',
  brandPrimaryDefault: 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  brandPrimaryLight: 'var(--color-brand-primary-light-new)',
  naturalGrayDarker2: 'var(--color-natural-gray-darker-2)',
};
```

Comment: `color` arg should be `keyof typeof colors`

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the type of the `colors` object items:

```
export const colors: { [key: string]: string; } = {
  'dark-grey': '#606060',
  'light-grey': '#909090',
  'slate-grey': '#7889a0',
  'olive-green': '#8fd683',
  'light-blue': '#0371ff',
  'dark-gray': '#4b6c89',
  'blue-700-new': 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  azure: '#1676ff',
  blue: '#1676ff',
  white: '#fff',
  black: '#000',
  brandPrimaryDefault: 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  brandPrimaryLight: 'var(--color-brand-primary-light-new)',
  naturalGrayDarker2: 'var(--color-natural-gray-darker-2)',
};
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7yQG2qgXHAbzgG0BrYAT33SgEtkBzAXWpjsYG44BfOAXkIAoOHADkAEwCGUUgFoGUSqPyiAxADYADFq2iANMLGZaDABYx5iisrGqAnJocP9h0akySYwS0pWqA7AAcgXaSmi4iohDGAG7eCsDAyDZqgQBm4uqBAMwRRibmsgBGmACuwCmqmtn%20AIxpaXkS0nIKktZ%20ACxF6gghTSXlsv6amrLIwADuKTHSABSysljQxVCSyOKyYHQAttIUsuLAaZKlmBYTkwCUeZIAXqWKfrXq-uoNeYPAz6-vjQYiSamWhePwNf6GEqSBCkPyjcIAuBFNYbAAKu32ABFjqdzipZlAFktoitketNttaHsoAcjiczhcpjdEWS0RiaQAZAowfHzRbLKCrclbdkHYxmRnXPLITyPSSYADiawomJawCgACZeYT%20STBTKYHLMJZ2oc1YKNczBNwOIJBKBILBECh0HAGMAYABhPX8OBzAWsdgMK6B%20gMfgAPmd2CgqGIAqYcAAPknozgAHRAkHADhAA) to playground.

Answer (score 0):

Your `colors` object expects specific keys to be used as an index, not just any string. You will want to use a union of the possible colours instead of `string`. For example:

```
export const colors = {
  'dark-grey': '#606060',
  'light-grey': '#909090',
  'slate-grey': '#7889a0',
  'olive-green': '#8fd683',
  'light-blue': '#0371ff',
  'dark-gray': '#4b6c89',
  'blue-700-new': 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  azure: '#1676ff',
  blue: '#1676ff',
  white: '#fff',
  black: '#000',
  brandPrimaryDefault: 'var(--color-brand-primary-default-new)',
  brandPrimaryLight: 'var(--color-brand-primary-light-new)',
  naturalGrayDarker2: 'var(--color-natural-gray-darker-2)',
};

export type Color = keyof typeof colors // 'dark-grey' | 'light-grey' | ...
export const getColor = (color: Color): string => colors[color] || colors.white;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7yQG2quBeOAbwCg44ByAEwEMoBrAWgHMpgBPcgLgoGIA2AAyDB5ADSkKmAJZMAFjGasO3cjwCcAjRrETyqTNRjBF7LrwDsADktrqAnWXIRpAN2MtgwZGdWWAZpR8lgDMDpIy8gwARpgArsA%20PALB5gCMfn5hVLSMLNTKvAAsUXwINlkx8QzmAgIMyMAA7j4utAAUDAxY0NFQ1MiUDGBQUgC2tGwMlMB%201LGYCg2NAJRh1ABesawqPKl85nwZYZXAO3sHR%20JkjbJSRjsZmVdwMdQIdDu19s9RfQMACiNxlA2AARGZzBYqVpQDpdZw9X79QbDMYTKYQ%20aLJqrH5-SiAtEggAyERg0PanW6UF6yKGQPR0jk2JWYWQhi21EwAHE%20mCcsAoAAmCmwqkImnsmCczCKfJTAU0oW44gAXwA3MRiKBILBECh0HAmMAYABhCX4OBtancdAjZBMZa2mD2pj4AB8%20uwUFQAG1qQBdOAAH2DXpwADobndgJrteBoPAYGwwMA4ObvZa6OwIH44MnU7nwz747qMAb4MazRKhZarTb0xKnXA7VIHR7i37AyGw9TUFHbkZNUA)